# Java Mockito: Cannot doReturn child classes?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am getting a `UnfinishedStubbingException` when I try to mock a method. I'm trying to have the `doReturn` return a mocked instance of a class that implements a specific interface.  That interface is the original return type of the method being mocked.

Here's an example of the class structure:

```
class A { 
    private C obj;

    C getObj() {
        return obj;
    }
}

class B implements C {
    void doCStuff() {}
    void doBStuff() {}
}

interface C {
    void doCStuff();
}
```

With this structure, I am trying to `mock A.getObj()` and have it return a mocked instance of `B`.

```
public void test() {
    A aObj = Mockito.mock(A.class);
    B bObj = Mockito.mock(B.class);

    Mockito.doReturn(bObj).when(aObj).getObj(); //throws UnfinishedStubbingException

    //Edit:
    B newB = (B)aObj.getObj();
    newB.doBStuff();
}
```

The problem is, I need to make `getObj` return a mocked instance of `B`, but I can't.  Normally in Java, I could polymorphically return an instance of `B` from a method that has a return type of `C`, since `B` implements `C`. However, it seems like a `doReturn` can't return instances of child classes that implement the original return type.

I hope I'm understanding this right, but am I doing something wrong or is there a work around for this?

Comment: Hold on. Your `.getObj()` returns a `C` anyway and not a `B`. This is probably what mockito is confused about...

Comment: Yeah, but a B is a C anyway.  It's understandable if mockito can't handle normal polymorphic calls, but I need a way to get around that.

Comment: Why? Your calling code can only ever use the functionality defined in the C interface (without an unsafe downcast). Since you're mocking, you won't be using any of B's concrete functionality anyways. Just return a mocked C.

Comment: Also, what happens when you try `Mockito.when(aObj.getObj()).thenReturn(bObj);`?

Comment: @TomG I didn't provide the full example due to complexity, but essentially I will eventually do `B b = (B) a.getObj();  b.doBStuff();` which will throw a `ClassCastException` if I mock out `C`.  And yes, I have tried the other way and it resulted into the same exception I got.

Comment: Is `b.doBStuff()` called in the test, the way you have shown it? That will still just be a call to a stubbed method...I'm not at all clear what you think you are demonstrating with this test, other than that Mockito itself works.

Comment: @TomG This was of course a very contrived example.  Sorry if it ended up very confusing, but the actual production code I'm working with is far more complex and convoluted.  That's why avoided using the actual code.  Anyway, if you were curious about the actual test, I was testing if fields from an object were being correctly transferred to a different object.  However, the point of the question was more `Mockito` related and less test related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I'm an idiot.  Turns out the method I was trying to mock was final and I didn't notice that originally.  It was from a super class and I assumed it was not final.  Methods that are final cannot be overridden and Mockito cannot mock them.

Here's a better example:

```
class A extends D {
    ...
}

class D {
    //Can't mock this.
    final Object getObj() { ... }
}
```

Turns out that you can still polymorphically return objects through Mockito, so false alarm on that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this will work; code is lacking to tell whether this will do the trick but maybe you can try this:

```
final C c = spy(new B());

final A a = spy(new A());

doReturn(c).when(a).getObj();
```

A more complete answer requires a more complete question ;)

Comment: The original question uses mocks, not spies -- the default behavior of calling through to real methods may not be obvious here...

Comment: @TomG yeah, I know; but then the provided code in the question does not really help matters. I can only do so much with the information I'm provided with ;)

Comment: I have tried this, and it did not work.  What extra information would make this question better?